# Logic App Sequential Runs Stuck "Waiting"

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App with a "When a HTTP request is received" trigger. I receive two concurrent posts from another application, though the posts are directly related, they just contain slightly different data points. This is simply due to a limitation within that application that it cannot combine the two posts into one. I unfortunately do not have any control over that.

To prevent some race condition issues within the remaining logic, we set the Concurrency Control to On with a Degree of Parallelism of 1, obviously only allowing one run at a time.

[image]

I receive one post, handle some logic, determine whether both have been received. If I determine it's only the first post, I Terminate the run with a status of Cancelled.

The issue I'm running into is that when the Logic App queues the second post, it doesn't always automatically trigger the run that's "Waiting." On rare occasion, it will trigger immediately after the first run. I've also seen it trigger within about 2 minutes after the first run. I've also seen it sit upwards of 20 minutes in the "Waiting" status before I just manually trigger the Logic App in order to get it to run.

This is commonly what I see:

[image]

The first run is handled, it's determined it's only the first of two posts, so there's logic to Cancel that run. However, the second post that came in at the same time remains in the "Waiting" status.

Any ideas what may be happening or how I can prevent this?

Comment: I tested it many times in my side and it always work fine, the second trigger executes immediately after cancel first running instance. Could you please provide more details such as the actions in your logic app ? Then I can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The HTTP requests contain a base64 encoded PDF and a few other properties. I'm saving the PDF to blob storage in a folder named after one of the properties (a unique ID, for example). I'm then checking that folder to see if both files are there. If only 1, it's the 1st POST, so I cancel. If 2 files are there, it's post 2 of 2, so I'm calling another Logic App to trigger a separate process.
The only way I can recreate this is if the trigger gets hit at pretty much the exact same time. Each run takes about 600-800 ms, so if the requests are even slightly spaced out, it handles it just fine.

Comment: I will also note that I tried using the Success option on the Terminate control, but experienced the same issue. Even though the 1st run is completed (whether using Cancel or Success on the Terminate control), the queued run will remain in the Waiting status, usually for an indefinite amount of time.