# Logic App runs sitting in waiting state after execution

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

After receiving a successful call for a "When a HTTP request is received" trigger. The Run goes into a waiting state for more than 10+ minutes with no way to force it to run, only 1 concurrent instance can run at a time but there are no previous runs still executing. Any further calls are also being put in a waiting state. There is also no way to cancel these runs.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Still in waiting state after 1 hour

Comment: we will need more information on what this logic app is doing, namely what actions are you attempting to run after HTTP request.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66995011/logic-app-sequential-runs-stuck-waiting

Unfortunately, I was never able to resolve it, so I redesigned my solution in order to allow for concurrent runs.

Comment: Hi both, there are some variable assignments after the trigger, from the log I can see none of those steps had started yet and the hour that it was waiting for doesn't show in the logs against any steps time take to execute.

Comment: May I know the Location of your logic app ?

Comment: It is in West EU @HuryShen

Comment: Does this problem happen every time when you trigger the logic app ?

Comment: not every time, seems to be intermittent

Comment: sometimes when there are multiple queued requests the next call can take 5 mins after the last one has finished to start also.

Comment: I've never come across this problem before and I did some test in my side just now with logic app in West EU and set concurrent instance to 1 but can't reproduce this problem. I'm afraid you can just ask Azure support team for help. You can create a support request to azure support team by following the steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance @HuryShen I will create a ticket and update this post with what they respond with

Comment: Did you get any explanation?